# Send email at a later time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am wondering if the `/v1.0/me/sendMail` has the ability to delay sending an email.  In the Outlook client, you can specify that you want your email sent at a later date and time. I've snooped around to see if there is a property that can be set on the message object to indicate this.

Did anyone find a way to get this working?  Of course, I could implement something in my software to handle the delayed sending, but why re-create something if it is already there.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve delayed sending of emails using extended properties. These can be set on the Graph API request payload using the "singleValueExtendedProperties" attribute.

The property to use is [PidTagDeferredSendTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203834(v=exchg.80).aspx) which has the ID 0x3FEF and type SystemTime.

The [id attribute of "singleValueExtendedProperties"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) takes different formats depending on the property you are setting.

For the deferred send time you would use `SystemTime 0x3FEF`.

**Example using a HTTP JSON POST Payload:**

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "bob@contoso.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": 
    [
      {
           "id":"SystemTime 0x3FEF",
           "value":"2019-01-29T20:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Example using the Microsoft Graph API client library:**

```
var client = /* Create and configure GraphServiceClient */;
var msg = new Message();

msg.ToRecipients = List<Recipient>(); 
msg.ToRecipients.Add(new Recipient() { 
  EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address ="bob@contoso.com" }
};

msg.Subject = "Meet for lunch?";
msg.Body = new ItemBody()
{
    Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
};

msg.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage();
msg.SingleValueExtendedProperties.Add(new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty()
{
    Id = "SystemTime 0x3FEF",
    Value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5).ToString("o")
});
await client.Me.SendMail(msg, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Send-Emails-until-a-9cee20cf

You set the deferred send time extended prop when creating the item.

Comment: I can see form that article that should be able to accomplish this with extended properties,

My emails are sent as JSON data.  I think I saw away to set extended properties.

Looks like the property id is: 16367 and the type for the date time is: [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::SystemTime

Will see what can be accomplished :)

Comment: Here is the JSON to add an extended property to the mail message. Just need to figure out the right id an value for deferred sending.

"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
      {
         "id":"String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e} Name Color",
         "value":"Green"
      }
    ]

Comment: Best I came up with is this:  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
     {
           "id":"String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1D} Name pidTagDeferredSendTime",
           "value":"2018-02-10T00:28:20"
     }
  ]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone know if this can be done via JSON sent to graph.microsoft.com?

Comment: Its a prop tag and therefore doesn't use a namespace guid.  Try  Id: "Integer 0x3FEF"