# Set Delay Delivery on emails using Outlook Javascript API

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am testing some code on Outlook 2016 & Outlook Web using [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab).

My use case is simple: when I click on a button in my addin, I want the email to be delivered **2 days after today** when it is sent. I know it is possible directly in the interface but this is just a test for a biggest addin later.

I am trying to set the **Delay Delivery** (or **Send Later** on Outlook Web) feature on emails through the Javascript API.
I went on the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-preview) but I was not able to find how to change the Delay Delivery property of emails.

**Is it possible to edit this property using the API?
Does anyone know how to do that?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can achieve the same by setting extended properties on the mail using Graph API. Please have a look at a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696033/send-email-at-a-later-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OfficeJS** doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. But you may consider using EWS, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services?view=outlook-js-1.9) for more information. The [How to: Delay sending an email message by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220496(v=exchg.80)) article explains how to delay sending an email message by using the EWS Managed API.

Another possible option is [Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696033/send-email-at-a-later-time).