# How to implement Microsoft Graph deferred sending

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to implement a deferred sending function to my site which currently sends email via Microsoft Graph. I have found some articles about `SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty` being used to defer sending, but so far has been unsuccessful with it.

My current code just ignores the deferred sending time and sends the email immediately.

```
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = Subject,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = bodyText
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = recipient
            }
        }
    },
};

message.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage
{
    new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty()
    {  
        Id = "SystemTime 0x3FEF",
        Value = DateTimeToSend.ToString("o")
    }
};

var saveToSentItems = true;

await graphServiceClient.Me
    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696033/send-email-at-a-later-time) they suggest that the ID should be `String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1D} Name pidTagDeferredSendTime` when passing as JSON but it looks like that was not successful for other. I checked and can confirm that it did not work for me either.

Comment: Is DateTimeToSend local time or universal? Dis you try to use Id = "String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1D} Name pidTagDeferredSendTime" instead of "SystemTime 0x3FEF"? If it makes any difference?

Comment: Really strange. Meanwhile I've tried to create a delayed message in outlook and read the value of single extended property `/me/{message-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x3FEF')` and it returns the correct value `"singleValueExtendedProperties": [{"id": "SystemTime 0x3fef", "value": "2022-12-02T11:00:00Z"}]` Could you use the query `/me/{message-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x3FEF')` and check if the property is present and what's the value?

Comment: Only difference is that C# .ToString("0") returns also milliseconds

Comment: I have adjusted the DateTime to be returned as the [format above](https://i.imgur.com/5erzC7u.png), but it still sends immediately. I have used both Id = "String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1D} Name pidTagDeferredSendTime" and "SystemTime 0x3FEF" both neither have the desired effect.

Comment: The property is present and has the following information: `"singleValueExtendedProperties": [{ "id": "SystemTime 0x3fef", "value": "2022-02-12T11:44:00Z" }]`

Comment: What if you create a draft message with the same body as you have now including singleValuesExtendedProperties and then send this draft? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Its important that the DateTime that you want the message to be sent is in UTC eg

"value": "2022-08-01T23:39:00Z"

Using local time won't work as Exchange does everything in UTC

Comment: I have adjusted the DateTime to be returned as the [format above](https://i.imgur.com/5erzC7u.png), but it still sends immediately.